# Date specific format in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Is there any way to store the below date in mysql table

> Date = 2017-01-05T00:00:00+05:30

```
//Table
create table test(dob DATETIME);

//Insert
insert into test(dob) values ('2017-01-05T00:00:00+05:30') // Throws error saying Incorrect datetime
```

Is there way I can insert the below date in mysql db from java code.

Comment: No dates are stored in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS` if you want to present the date or collect the date in another format you will have to do some date conversion on it in the presentation layer

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Date` object, good. Otherwise, parse the string into a `Date` object using `SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
Date d = sdf.parse("2017-01-05T00:00:00+05:30");
```

Then you can make a PreparedStatement to do the date insert like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into test(dob) values (?)");
ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(d.getTime()));
ps.executeUpdate();
```